# Solving Ordinary Integro-delayed differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

I have an ordinary integro-differential equation of the form $$y''(t)+C_1y(t)+C_2\int_{0}^{t}f(t-\tau)y''(\tau)d\tau +C_3\int_{0}^{t}f(t-\tau)y(\tau)d\tau=0$$ where $C_1$,$C_2$ and $C_3$ are constants.

I know that finding an analytical solution can be hard. How can I solve this numerically?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to look for an analytic solution solution using Laplace transforms or using power series. 
$$y(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n$$

After your edit Laplace transform seems good as you can solve this equation as a third order ODE for :
$$Y(t)=\int_{0}^{t}y(\tau)d\tau$$
And you should have noticed that :
$$\int_{0}^{t}y''(\tau)d\tau=y'(t)-y'(0)=Y''(t)-Y''(0)$$
Thus your equation becomes :
$$Y'''(t)+C_1Y'(t)+C_2(Y''(t)-Y''(0))+C_3Y(t)=0$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm sorry that I have missed an important term in my equation. I'll edit it now. Nevertheless your approach gave me an insight into solving the problem. Thanks again.